# SQL query using a foreign key that may be NULL that returns values based on NULL columns in related table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, Root and Linked, with root.LinkedId a Foreign Key into Linked like so:

Table "**root**":

| id | name | LinkedId | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sales | 1 | 214-444-1934 |
| 2 | R&D | NULL | 555-111-1834 |
| 3 | Sales | 2 | 214-222-1734 |
| 4 | Finance | 3 | 817-333-1634 |
| 5 | Sales | NULL | 214-555-1434 |

Table "**linked**":

| id | name | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Best1 | qqq |
| 2 | NewTec | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | www |

I want to return an EMPTY String if the root.LinkedId value is NULL.

If root.LinkedId points to a row in the Linked table, I want to return only the Linked.name if Linked.code is NULL. If linked.name is NULL, the return vale will be an EMPTY String no matter what is in linked.code.

If root.LinkedId points to a row in the Linked table and Linked.name is NOT NULL AND Linked.code is NOT NULL, I want to return Linked.name + Linked.code.

I have gotten as far as this:

```
select linkedId, name, code
from Linked a
left join root b on b.LinkedId = a.Id
where b.LinkedId is not null
```

I can't figure out how to vary my return value based on these combinations.

This is what I expect:

```
For root.Id == 1 or 5, THEN ""
For root.LinkedId == 1, THEN "Best1 qqq"
For root.LinkedId == 2, THEN "NewTec"
For root.LinkedId == 3, THEN ""
```

Comment: Have you tried a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression? Tip: Useful table aliases make it easier to understand a query, something `a` and `b` do not do. And they should be applied to all column references, e.g. to clarify which `name` should be returned. It also helps to avoid problems caused as tables are altered, e.g. if someone added a `code` column to the `root` table.

Answer (score 0):

>= SQL 2017

```
SELECT CASE WHEN l.name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT_WS(' ',l.[name],l.[code]) END from [Root] r
LEFT JOIN [linked] l ON l.[id] = r.[LinkedID]
```

< SQL 2017

```
SELECT CASE WHEN l.name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE l.[name] + ISNULL(' ' + code,'') END from [Root] r
LEFT JOIN [linked] l ON l.[id] = r.[LinkedID]
```

This is if you specifically want a BLANK return. Otherwise change `''` to `NULL`. When you use `CONCAT()`, you'll return a true concatenation. Whenever you concatanate using `+`, remember **`NULL + anything = NULL`**